# display vimeo video with ng-repeat angularjs videojs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, vimeo, video.js

I'm trying to display video with angularjs 
here is my code:

```
<span class="video-inner" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <video id="video-{{item.id}}"
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls
        preload="auto"
        width="600"
        height="200"
        data-setup='{
            "techOrder": ["vimeo"],
            "sources": [
                { "type": "video/vimeo", "src": {{item.video}} }
            ]
        }'>
    </video>
</span>
```

And data:

```
   $scope.items = [
       {id: 1, video: "https://vimeo.com/63186969"},
       {id: 2, video: "https://vimeo.com/63186969"}
   ];
```

here is example I used:
https://static.bini.io/cus-videos/
but it doesn't working
what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you need to interpolate it with `{{}}`:

```
 <video id="video-item.id"
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls
        preload="auto"
        width="600"
        height="200"
        data-setup='{
            "techOrder": ["vimeo"],
            "sources": [{ "type": "video/vimeo",
            "src": item.video}]
            }'>
 </video>
```